# Check if element is part of stack

Tags: c++, stack

I need to check if element is part of a stack. Here is the function that I have written:

```
template<class T>
    bool CheckElem(Stack<T>& A, T x)
      {
        Stack<T> B;
        bool check = false;
        while(!A.Empty())
          {
            if(A.Top() == x) check = true;
            B.Push(A.Top());
            A.Pop();               
          }
        A = B;
        if(check) return true;
        return false;
      }
```

Like you see I need to Pop all elements of the stack to be able to check for example the last element of the stack. And I'm saving the elements in another stack, so I won't loose my data. But the elemets are reversed like they are entered in the second stack and in fact it is becoming something like a linked list. 
My question is if there is another way to check if element is in stack without need of poping and saving the elements of the stack on another place.

Comment: If this is for a class or something similar and you want to treat this as a `pure` stack then no there is no other way.

Comment: Do you have to implement the stack as is or you can change so that the stack will be implemented with vector inside?

Comment: NOTE that you need somehow to revers B before you do `A = B;`

Comment: You shouldn't be using stack if you are not dealing with the top most element.

Comment: I want to do this because I'm practising my stack coding skills. A program like that can be easily written with arrays but I want to do it with stack.

Comment: Well, I'd love to train myself to dig holes with spoons, but they're not the right tools for that task. Similarly, a stack is not the right tool for what you're trying to accomplish :v

Answer (score 0):

> My question is if there is another way to check if element is in stack

The [stack interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) has no functions that support inspecting arbitrary elements, I'm afraid.

> the elemets are reversed like they are entered in the second stack

The way to fix this is to pop everything out of the second stack and push them back into the original stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat this as a `pure` stack then there is no other way to do this. You can see that [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) does not provide you with any interface to examine arbitrary elements in the `stack`.

If this is not the case then, you don't want a `stack` something like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) makes more sense for random access to elements of the container.

Comment: Thaks for the advice. I reached the chapter about vectors yet. I was just wondering if there is a better way for writing this task with stack, because I'm on the stack chapter now. :)

Comment: @SinanZikri, There are exercises that actually work well with stacks. I would find some of those instead of trying to use it for something it's not meant to be used for.

Comment: @SinanZikri Understood, there is not way other way, that is one of the limitation of the `stack` data structure. As chris said look for algorithms that use stacks, this page has some good examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I understand. Can you suggest me a source with stack exercises if you know any, please? :)

Comment: @SinanZikri This is one example I found code is in python but some good exercises: http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/BasicDS/stacks.html if you search of algorithms and stack you should find plenty more.